# Запрет масштабирования карты с помощью пальцев

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, google-maps

Есть js гугл карта, которая никоим образом вообще никак не должна масштабироваться.
Для компьютера достаточно этого:

```
zoomControl: false,
    scaleControl: false,
    scrollwheel: false,
    disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
    disableDefaultUI: true
```

Но на мобильных, на андроиде в частности, карта продолжает масштабироваться стандартными жестами для приближения/отдаления.

Как вот на 110% не дать карте ни единого шанса на масштабирование?

P.S. И я говорю именно о масштабировании карты, на масштабирование сайта мне всёравно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stackoverflow подсказывает нам такой ответ:

```
var tblock = function (e) {
    if (e.touches.length > 1) {
        e.preventDefault()
    }
    return false;
}

document.getElementById("mapWrapperId").addEventListener("touchmove", tblock, true);
```

Вместо mapWrapperId подставьте id родительского для карт блока.

*Источник: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729067/gmaps-v3-disable-pinch-to-zoom-on-ipad-safari*

Comment: Нет, драгабл это перемещение карты, а мне нужно масштабирование.

Comment: @Diskyp изменил ответ, попробуйте новый код.

Comment: Да, этот код решил мою проблему, спасибо вам!

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можете создать прозрачный div поверх карты

Comment: Тогда я полностью не смогу с ней взаимодействовать, а мне нужно только масштабирование убрать.